# HDFS: yarn export kills when some datanodes run out of space but there are still nodes with plenty of space

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, distcp

We have 2 Hadoop clusters. We want to export an Hbase snapshot from one cluster to the other. The target cluster is composed of 3 datanodes of 128TB and 5 datanodes of 28TB each. Everything goes smoothly until the 5 smallest datanodes reach the occupancy limit. At that moment the yarn task launched in the other cluster begins to complain with the following messages:

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException):
File /hbase/archive/data/default/HBASE/57e8bf457599cd0dbee2fb0fc407f312/D/bdc14899028f48a2ba8a747e00554304
could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 8 datanode(s) running and 8 node(s) are excluded in this operation. 
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2278)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2808)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:905)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:577)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1086) 
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1029) 
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:957) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) 
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2957) 
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1498) 
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1444) 
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1354) 
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:510)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1078)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1865)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1668)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
```

Finally the yarn task ends up killing the export.
Is there a parameter that tells the cluster to continue writing to the rest of the cluster that has enough space? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could [write a BlockPlacementPolicy.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385).

You can tweak your rack settings a little to try and juice your odds a little.  I can't think of a strategy off hand but I'm sure there are better and worse strategies.

Lets reframe the problem:

Why not simply turn off the 5 small data nodes during this operation?

Why not reduce replication to 1 for this folder/snapshot you are creating. It would reduce the file requirements by 2/3.  This is only safe to do if the snapshot is not critical.  Even turning down replication to 2 would save space, and might be just enough for it to complete. (Then it could be moved safely to the other cluster)

Why not create a third cluster(with the small nodes) and use namespace federation to better handle the data.  This would likely really be a longer term solution that would make life better.

Comment: No so obvious for me the link you provided. Any way thanks.
We turned off the small datanodes and it worked, but the table size is nearly all the 3 datanodes size, we are afraid next time we have to do it, it can't fit there.
We did the export with a replication of 1 (yes, we know it is risky but we don't have any other chance).
I thought it would be easier to do that. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer. I really apreciate it!!!

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you feel this was the answer and you feel comfortable, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: If you feel this answer was helpful and you are comfortable could you mark it as correct?